# $H^1(X, G_1 \times G_2)$ in terms of simpler first cohomologies

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a variety over a field $k$ of characteristic 0 (**not** necessarily with $k = \bar{k}$). Let $G_1, G_2$ be linear algebraic groups over $k$. My question is:

> Can I write $H^1(X, G_1 \times G_2)$ in terms of $H^1(X, G_1)$ and $H^1(X, G_2)$ (or any other "simpler" things)?

Comment: Is this sheaf cohomology? If so, then then you can use the Künneth formula (see [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34673/kunneth-formula-for-sheaf-cohomology-of-varieties) discussion on mathoverflow.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer But in the Kunneth formula, we also have $X\times Y$, which I don't want.

Comment: @user194368 Is this sheaf cohomology on the Zariski site of $X$, or some other site? What's your definition of $H^1$, since $G_i$ is almost certainly non-abelian--do you just want the standard pointed set of non-abelian cohomology? If $G_i$ were abelian, then the answer would just be the direct sum of the cohomologies of the individual groups. I'd have to think about what this would mean/if you can even say anything, if the $G_i$ are non-abelian.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I'm on the etale site, and yes, $H^1$ is just the standard pointed set. Can I ask why if the $G_i$ were abelian we would have the direct sum of the cohomologies? Is $H^1(X,-)$ exact in that case?

Comment: @user194368 If $X$ is qcqs then etale cohomology commutes with arbitrary direct sums (I don't even think you need qcqs for finite, but I included it to be safe). You essentially just take an injective resolution of each, and the direct sum will be an injective resolution of the direct sum. This allows you to immediately conclude. EDIT: I think the annoying finiteness conditions come in if you want to do infinite direct sums. Something about arbitrary direct sums of injective modules being injective iff the ring is Noetherian.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Ha, I see. No, I'm considering just finite direct sums. Do you know what $X$ should be then? PS. If you write your answer with slightly more details, I'll accept it.

Comment: @user194368 But, I don't know/haven't thought too hard about what goes on if $G_i$ are non-abelian.